# Mypy can't infer type from TypedDict.get(Optional[key], str)

Tags: python, mypy

I'm asking here before opening an issue because I'm not sure if this is expected behavior. My felling tells me that it has to do with runtime checking but I'm not sure,

I have this MVE

```py
from typing import Optional
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

D = TypedDict("D", {"bar": Optional[str]})


def foo() -> None:
    a: D = {"bar": ""}
    a.get("bar", "").startswith("bar")
```

mypy will complain:

```
Item "None" of "Optional[str]" has no attribute "startswith"
```

Now is pretty obvious that since second argument  of get is an string, the return has .startswith, but still the error. I'm using `# type:ignore`  on this, is there any other way?

Comment: `Optional[str]` means that the value for the key "bar" can be a string or `None`. The second argument to `get()` is only returned when the dictionary does not contain the key, not when the value of the key is `None`, `a.get("bar", "")` could return `None` if the value of `a['bar']` was equal to `None`

Comment: Nice catch!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Optional[T]` represents a `T` or `None`, so `a: D = {"bar": None}` would typecheck and that’s why `a.get("bar", "").startswith("bar")` can’t. If you’re okay with *every* key in the `TypedDict` being optional, there’s [`total=False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict):

```py
D = TypedDict("D", {"bar": str}, total=False)
```

Comment: Hmmm, this seems the right thing to do in my case, thanks I will try it